# C# download file from the web

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, download, textreader

Is there a way to make the following function work **via proxy**?

`public T[] ReadStream(System.IO.TextReader reader);`

I want to be able to proxify the `reader` instance, so that it could **download a file from the web** on reading attempts and cache it somewhere.

Or maybe there is something default for this purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use WebClient.DownloadFile. If you need a proxy, you can set the Proxy property of your WebClient object.

Here's an example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Proxy = new WebProxy("some.proxy.com", 8000);
    client.DownloadFile("example.com/file.jpg", "file.jpg");
}
```

You can also download the file by parts with a BinaryReader:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Proxy = new WebProxy("some.proxy.com", 8000);

    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(client.OpenRead("example.com/file.jpg")))
    {
        reader.ReadByte();
        reader.ReadInt32();
        reader.ReadBoolean();

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: What you suggest is the obvious way. When I was talking about `proxy`, I meant some object that would sequentially cache the file from the web and reroute all `read`-like calls from the appropriate interface to that cached piece of file. So that I could say `TextReader t = new MyCustomWebReader("http://www.site.com/file.zip");` and it would read it (with some pauses, obviously).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you ask for.

Comment: Similiar to this, where `StreamReader` is being constructed on top of web query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842038/streamreader-and-reading-an-xml-file

Comment: I want the same for arbitrary remote files.

Comment: Not necessary proxified, just simply wrap a query in `StreamReader` so that it downloads and reads the file sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want?  I am also slightly confused by the wording of the question, given your comments to the previous answer.

```
public StreamReader GetWebReader(string uri)
{
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    return new StreamReader(responseStream);
}
```

Comment: Nice, if this wasn't the answer I wrote 15 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var webRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://whatever");
var response = webRequestObject.GetResponse();
var webStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Ta-da.
var reader = new StreamReader(webStream);
```