# Read an XML file from http address

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stream

I need to read an xml file using c#/.net from a source like so: `https://10.1.12.15/xmldata?item=all`

That is basically just an xml file.

StreamReader does not like that.

What's the best way to read the contents of that link?

The file looks like so:

```
- <RIMP>
     - <HSI>
       <SBSN>CZ325000123</SBSN> 
       <SPN>ProLiant DL380p Gen8</SPN> 
       <UUID>BBBBBBGGGGHHHJJJJ</UUID> 
       <SP>1</SP> 
       <cUUID>0000-000-222-22222-333333333333</cUUID> 
- <VIRTUAL>...
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842038/streamreader-and-reading-an-xml-file

Comment: Read about [XDocument Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301598.aspx)

Comment: @EliGassert: That question is based on HttpWebRequest and XmlDocument -- two very dated options to work with HTTP and XML in C# respectively.

Comment: The top two answers are exactly what he's trying to do.  The accepted answer reads the contents then loads the text into an XmlDocument; the second answer shows that you can load a document by URL, which is also the top-trending answer in this thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to do this is using the `XmlDocument` class. A lot of servers around the world are still running .Net Framework < 3.0 so it's good to know that this class still exists alongside `XDocument`in case you're developing an application that will be run on a server.

```
string url = @"https://10.1.12.15/xmldata?item=all";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(url);
```

Comment: This works just fine. I am just a bit stuck at trying to read one node at a time. I have this: `<SMB><FIELD NAME="Product Name" VALUE="ProLiant DL380p Gen8"/>
  <FIELD NAME="Serial Number" VALUE="12345678"/>
  <FIELD NAME="UUID" VALUE="BRRTGHHH4529"/>
  <FIELD NAME="cUUID" VALUE="000000-4139-11111-3332"/></SMB>` I just want to select the Serial Number value, how do I do that, `GetAttributeNode("NAME")` just gives back "Product Name" but I want the second NAME and VALUE for the serial number

Comment: `XmlNode myNode = xmlDoc.GetSingleNode("//FIELD[@NAME='Serial Number']/@VALUE");`

Answer (score 15):

You'll want to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to process the XML file. The [XDocument.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) supports loading an XML document from an URI:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("https://10.1.12.15/xmldata?item=all");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the correct answer must starting by reading the initial question about how to "Read an XML file from a URL (or in this case from a Http address)".

I think that can be the best for you see the next easy demos:

(In this case XmlTextReader but today you can use XmlReader instead of XmlTextReader)
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307643

(Parallel you could read this documentation too).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

regards