# Add news to c# application

Tags: c#, rss, newsletter, feed

We have a c# application wich is used by user to do stuff ;-)

What I want is to add at the startpage of the application some news or information like "hey, there is a new update for the application" or "did you know this feature..." Basically I want something similar like the startpage in Visual Studio.

The news should remain when there is no internet connection and update when there are new entires.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you  [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399400/best-way-to-read-rss-feed-in-net-using-c-sharp) ?

Comment: Yep. But wasn't sure if rss is the right way. Since I want to keep the news even when the user is offline.

Comment: Well for this you obviously need to provide some storage. Both should complement each other.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll try with RSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your application read some data from file located in the server (XML is good idea), Also you must save the current version of your app in some file (or some where).

So after comparing between the two values you can decide what to show in your news bar.

To show some news you can just read it from another XML file in the server, Then organized it like you want.

here is good ways to read XML from server [Read an XML file from http address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160848/read-an-xml-file-from-http-address)

Comment: Thanky you very much!  I realized it with reading the news with syndication feed and write the them to a local html file. The news are being displayed with the webbrowser control.