# Loop through returned XML Result and assign values

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I'm currently calling a external MVC Controller and passing in two parameters which passes back an XML Result how I'm currently doing this is as follows, please be aware my experience with XML is pretty much 0

```
 try
     {
         var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"] + String.Format("/ws/RetailerBrandsFiltered?postcode={0}&countryCode={1}", model.Postcode, model.SelectedCountry);

         // Create the request to call the external mvc controller to retrieve the retailers
         var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
         req.Method = "GET";
         req.ContentType = "xml";

         // Do the request to external controller
         var stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
         var responce = stIn.ReadToEnd();

         foreach (var item in responce)
         {
             string urn = item["URN"].InnerText
         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
     }
```

I'm trying to loop through the response and get the XML nodes out and assign them to a model (which I haven't implemented yet) but for testing I'm trying to get the first value and assign it to a string.

Which isn't working the message is Cannot apply indexing to type char, ideally my for loop would look something like this.

```
 foreach (var item in responce)
 {
     string urn = item["URN"].InnerText;
     string name = item["NAME"].InnerText;
     string address = item["ADDRESS"].InnerText;
 }
```

Again once this is working, I will replace the string's with model binding. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Follow the types. responce is a string. So, item is just a character from the string.

Comment: @JustinPihony sorry don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842038/streamreader-and-reading-an-xml-file should resolve your problem. Right now you are just reading in a plain string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `reponce` is a string and when you try to iterate over it, you're implicitly casting the string to a `char[]`and iterating over that.

Load the stream into a `XDocument` and use Linq to get the values:

```
try
{
     var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"] + string.Format("/ws/RetailerBrandsFiltered?postcode={0}&countryCode={1}", model.Postcode, model.SelectedCountry);

     // Create the request to call the external mvc controller to retrieve the retailers
     var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     req.Method = "GET";
     req.ContentType = "xml";

     // Do the request to external controller
     var xDoc = XDocument.Load(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

     // Get some nodes
     var items = xDoc.Descendants("item");

     foreach(var item in items)
     {
         string urn = item.Element("URN").Single().Value;
         // Do more stuff
     }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex);
 }
```

Se [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml) for more details.